# Calculate all possible paths in graph

Tags: graph-theory, recursive-algorithms, searching

I have a number of graphs that look similar to this:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v62sf.png)

In this image, there are 4 levels and 4 node per level: Green is level 1, Blue is level 2, Pink is level 3 and Yellow is level 4.

[Graph - Text Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2okQL.png)

To calculate the paths from node 1 (ana) to node 200 (sara), if the graph is directed, the total number of paths is equal to number of nodes per level ^ number of levels like in this table:
[Table - Directed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmWA3.png)

If the graph is undirected, the number of paths grows exponencially but I can't find the relationship between the number of levels and the number of nodes per level to get the ammount of paths.
I am using prolog with a recursive dfs algorythm to get these values but, as the values keep increasing, the ammount of time increases as well.
Here is a table with all the data I have for the undirected graph:
[Table - Unidirected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfvkU.png)

Comment: You might find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Matrix_powers) to be interesting. For an undirected graph you can [diagonalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization) the matrix to compute high powers (and from this you can see that the number of paths does indeed grow exponentially -- it's approximately a scale multiple of $\lambda^n$ for $\lambda$ the largest eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix).

Comment: By the way, this matrix power technique (minus doing fancy linear algebra like diagonalization) is equivalent to doing dynamic programming, where the subproblem is "how many paths of length n are there between these two nodes" for every pair of nodes.  With this information you can work out how many length n+1 paths there are between pairs of nodes.

Comment: Significantly, your graph is multipartite. Multipartite graphs have well-behaved adjacency matrices as with respect to modifying parts, and as @kyle miller noted, the adjacency matrix (and in particular, eigenvalues) encodes information about $k$-walks. Van Miegham has some excellent references on relations between eigenvalues and walk structure, and his results are entirely self contained.